# decimal to hour error 01850 in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal, hour

I have a column of hours in this format

```
HOUR
0 (meaning 0:00)
0.5 (meaning 0:30)
until 
23.5 (meaning 23:30)
```

I want to transform these decimals to real hours so I wrote the following code on pl sql

```
select TO_DATE (cast(hour as integer)||':'||round((cast(hour as int)-hour)*60,2),'HH24:MI') as f_hour
from half_hour
```

but now I'm getting ORA 01850: hour must be between 0 and 23
any help?

Comment: 'Real hours' would be expressed as an `interval day to second`. Did you actually want dates, or maybe strings in the format `HH24:MI`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. `FLOOR` will make sure, you get 23 for 23.5 in your table

```
select TO_DATE (cast(FLOOR(hour) as integer)||':'||round((cast(hour as int)-hour)*60,2),'HH24:MI') as f_hour
from half_hour;
```

`CAST as INTEGER` does rounding, 23.5 becomes 24.

The above however, assumes, that you always have time in multiples of 30 minutes.

I would have used something like below, which doesn't require time to be in multiples of 30 minutes

```
select TO_DATE (FLOOR(hour) || ':'|| mod(hour,  floor(hour) )*60,'HH24:MI') as f_hour
    from half_hour;
```

Explanation -

```
Input - 12.6
FLOOR(INPUT) - 12
MOD(INPUT, FLOOR(INPUT)) - 0.6
MOD(INPUT, FLOOR(INPUT))*60 - 36 <-- this is your minutes.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was missing something, but I could not figure out what was it

Comment: @mnd - Updated the answer with an easier to understand and concise solution. And also - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Again, thank you so much. In this case, I just have the data in 30 minutes, but it's good to have the reference for different situations. In the case of trying to display only the hour should I use TO_CHAR instead of TO_DATE?

Comment: You won't need to_char as well, isn't it ? Just the floor() function will give you that value. That is if you only want the hour

Comment: Nice! But then I'm getting results like 13:0 when I don't have 30 min. Would this be a problem when doing an inner join by hour, for example?

Comment: Why use the whole thing ? Why not just do `select floor(hour) from half_hour` if you only want hour

Comment: the thing is I need the hour in the format of 13:00, for example, because I will need to make a join with another table that has the hour in the format of 13:00.

Comment: Then use to_date along with `select floor(hour) from half_hour`